# quiero registrar en un crud con el patron mvc en php con mysql y me sale este error :

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, crud

Excepción PDO no detectada:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: error general: 1364 El campo 'MDC__IDENTIFICACION' no
> tiene un valor predeterminado en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\modelo\medicos_modelo.php:14 Rastreo de pila:
> #0 C: \xampp\htdocs\Hospital\modelo\medicos_modelo.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\controlador\medicos_controlador.php(26):
> medicos_modelo::registrar(Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\libs\rutas.php(15):
> medicos_controlador->registrar() #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\index.php(14): Rutas::cargarContenido('
> medicos', 'registrar') #4 {main} lanzado en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\modelo\medicos_modelo.php en la línea 14

```
public static function registrar($datos){
    $obj = new conexion();
    $c = $obj->getConexion();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO T_MEDICOS (MDC_NOMBRESS, MDC_APELLIDOS)
            VALUES 
            (?, ?)";

            $st = $c->prepare($sql);
            $v = array ($datos["nombres"], $datos["apellidos"]);
            return $st->execute($v);
}
```

Si necesitan más fotos me dicen, gracias.

Comment: Puedes indicar tu definición de BBDD para la tabla T_MEDICOS? Por lo que parece te falta indicar en la consulta el campo mdc_dentificacion.

Comment: Huele a que el campo de tu tabla `MDC__IDENTIFICACION`, quizás quieres que sea autoincrementable y olvidaste setearlo como tal.

Comment: Hola. No necesitamos fotos, sino ver la estructura de la tabla, si es como texto mejor. Puedes obtenerla ejecutando un `SHOW CREATE TABLE T_MEDICOS;` en el programa que usas para manejar la base de datos.